# Adding a list as an element in another list

Tags: haskell

Hi I'm just starting to learn haskell but I need some help with a part of a function that I'm building. The code won't even compile as it is and I don't understand what's wrong. I'm trying to add a list as an element to another list.

```
add (z:zs) = [z, head zs] : add zs
```

All elements are strings. `z:zs = [String]`
I think the type is

```
add :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
```

but the error messeage I get is: "The type of signature for 'add` lacks an accompanying binding.

I want it to create pairs: `[1,2,3,4] -> [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`

Comment: please include all relevant code. see [mcve].

Comment: Also, what do you think the type of `:` is?

Comment: Your code compile if no type signature is in `add`. Probably is doesn't do what you expect. Plase tell us whats the expected behaviour and we'll try to explain for beginners

Comment: Namely, what is `add [1,2,3]` supposed to produce?

Comment: The code you give compiles without issue, but you'll have trouble running it on a finite list. (`Prelude.head: empty list`). Is this the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure what error your actually getting but your code doesn’t do what you want it to. My best theory is that you’re typing it into ghci (where one needs to do weird things to send multiple lines together).

Let’s look at your code. I think this is it:

```
add (z:zs) = [z, head zs] : add zs
```

Lets break it up. On the left hand side of the `=`, you are partially declaring the function `add` (partially because you are allowed to declare another case which matches the arguments differently on another line). The case you define is for a non-empty list `z:zs`. The first element is bound to `z` and the rest of the list is `zs`. If the function is given an empty list, this pattern won’t match. As the function has no definition with a pattern which will match `[]`, you would get an error.

On the right hand side, we construct a list using the `:` constructor. Again on the left hand side we have the first element and on the right hand side we have the rest. The first element is constructed to be a list of whatever type `z` is. The types work out ok so far because `head zs` has the same type as `z` (but note it will fail if `zs` is `[]`. The rest of the lists comes from recursively calling `add`. The compiler can deduce the type of `add` is therefore:

```
add :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

That is, it takes a list of something of type and returns a list of lists of things of that type.

We can imagine evaluating it on the start of a list (fake syntax below):

```
add [1, 2, 3, ...]
  -> [1,2] : add [2, 3, ...]
  -> [1,2] : [2,3] : ...
  == [[1,2],[2,3], ...]
```

Your function was nearly right but as soon as you give it a finite list it will blow up at the end. Also you used square brackets to make a list when you meant to make a tuple.

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
add :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
add [] = []
add [ _ ] = []
add (x1:x2:xs) = (x1,x2) : add (x2:xs)
```

And here is another way using functions from prelude:

```
add :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
add [] = []
add xs@(_:tail) = zip xs tail
```